# Converting NetCDF to grib2: problem in save in grib2 format

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-iris

I'm using Iris module to convert from netcdf to grib2:

```
import iris

cubes = iris.load('SST.nc')       # each variable in the netcdf file is a cube
data=cubes[0]

data.coord('lat').coord_system=iris.coord_systems.GeogCS(4326)
data.coord('lon').coord_system=iris.coord_systems.GeogCS(4326)
print (data)
iris.save(data, 'SST_test.grib2')  # save a specific variable to grib
```

But I can't save in grib2! I saw other users can do it with the same iris module, but I don't know where is the problem. I got the following error: `"Unable to save GRIB file - "iris_grib" package is not installed."`

I've just installed iris 2.2.0 in Python 3.7. The iris_grib module is not available to Python 3.7.

Comment: I would recommend using [miniconda](https://docs.conda.io/en/latest/miniconda.html)  to take care of the different dependencies. Create a new conda environment containing all the Python modules that you need.

Comment: I used Iris module with miniconda, but it didn't work.

Comment: You also need to include iris-grib as the error message clearly states. So the actual problem  is not in your code but rather in installation of the right packages.

Comment: I tried to install iris-grib module, but it didn't in Python 3.7. However, in the following example didn't use iris-grib module: https://github.com/rsignell-usgs/ipython-notebooks/blob/master/files/Iris_CFSR_wave_wind.ipynb